# OnMouseOver function for QuadCurve Java

Tags: java, mouse, curve

im creating a program for drawing graphs but I have a problem, I need to know if the mouse is over a QuadCurve. How would create the function that function?
the program I'm doing is to draw graphs (draw nodes and edges). to draw the edges with the mouse at a point just press the JPanel and drag to the end point and is drawn with Graphics2D QuadCurve2D object and stored in an array of objects. each object in the object is saved QuadCurve2D and it contains 3 points (start, control, end), now I need a method to eliminate any edge that this drawn on the JPanel and for this each edge must have a method that takes as a parameter the mouse point and returns true if the point is on the curve

Comment: would you give us more information about what are you trying to do you could use a short, self contained correct example http://sscce.org/

Comment: the program I'm doing is to draw graphs (draw nodes and edges). to draw the edges with the mouse at a point just press the JPanel and drag to the end point and is drawn with Graphics2D QuadCurve2D object and stored in an array of objects. each object in the object is saved QuadCurve2D and it contains 3 points (start, control, end), now I need a method to eliminate any edge that this drawn on the JPanel and for this each edge must have a method that takes as a parameter the mouse point and returns true if the point is on the curve

Comment: I am also experiencing this problem. Did you ever find a solution? If so, could you explain it for me?

Answer (score 0):

Hook up a mouse motion listener to your panel, then on mouse motion events use the intersects method on the QuadCurve2D object to detect whether it hits a rectangle centered on the mouse cursors new position. Experiment with the width and height parameters to find what feels best for you.

Comment: thanks for responding but the Intersect method not only returns true if the point is on the curve, but also returns true if the point is within the area that creates the curve, I just need to come first.

Comment: Then just use a pixel-sized square.

Comment: I do not think I explained properly, in this picture you can see what I need to help me please http://i.stack.imgur.com/Em3Y9.png a method to determine if a point (the point of the mouse and what I have ) is inside the curve (QuadCurve2D object), the Intersect or Contains method returns true if the point is outside the curve http://i.stack.imgur.com/WTdbM.png (across the red painted returns true) and I do not want that.